# Error when creating an instance of Word in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, ms-word

I am getting an error when I run this app in VS 2010 (it works fine in VS 2008)

Private Sub GenerateInvoice()

```
Dim emptyObject As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

Dim wordApp As New Word.Application
wordApp.Visible = True

Dim InvoiceDoc As New Word.Document
InvoiceDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(InvoicePath, emptyObject, emptyObject, emptyObject)

Dim totalFields As Integer = 0

For Each mergeField As Word.Field In InvoiceDoc.Fields
```

The error occurs at the For Each line

> "Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object."

Am I missing something here?

Comment: BTW, there is no need to CSharpify VB with things like `Dim emptyObject As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value`. Just don't enter the values and name the optional parameter(s) like `Dim InvoiceDoc As New Word.Document = wordApp.Documents.Add(Template:=InvoicePath)`. Less code - C# is so verbose. :)

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890905/delay-when-creating-microsoft-office-interop-word-application for the same exception, but a different root problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the `InvoicePath` used in the instance run via VS2010 is invalid and so the call to `Documents.Add` fails?

Are you running both VS2010 and VS2008 on the same machine? And is the `InvoicePath` set to the exact same path in both instances?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 Dim InvoiceDoc As Word.Document
 wordApp.Documents.Add(InvoicePath, emptyObject, emptyObject, emptyObject)
 InvoiceDoc=wordApp.ActiveDocument
```

Comment: error on ActiveDocument line: "This command is not available because no document is open."

Comment: Maybe InvoicePath does not point to the correct location of your doc template?